# Invalid Object when trying to add to SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to be able to type in the name of the table to add values too. I have it set to a `Textbox` in the `sqlcommand`. I get the "Invalid Object" error. What am I doing wrong. If I manually type in the name of the table in the code it works but when trying to do it from a `textbox` it does not.

```
string tableSelected = stateTextBox.Text + "Geo";
string sqlcomm = ("INSERT INTO [" + tableSelected + "] (Name, Type) VALUES (@Name, @Type)");
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbLocation);
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlcomm, conn);
conn.Open();
string[] cities = citiesTextBox.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] counties = countiesTextBox.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] federal = positionsFederalTextBox.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] state = positionsStateTextBox.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] local = positionsLocalTextBox.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", SqlDbType.NChar);
foreach (string city in cities)
{
    comm.Parameters["@Name"].Value = city;
    comm.Parameters["@Type"].Value = "City";
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging what `string sqlcomm` returns?

Comment: Yes, and that is what returns "Invalid Object name ' content from textbox'

Comment: The exception probably occurs because the table name coming from the textbox is non existent in your database. Note that your are adding the `"Geo"` word after the textbox value;

Comment: Right. For example the table name is "AlabamaGeo". So, in the Textbox it says the state. ie: Alabama. In the string I need to add "Geo" to is so it links to the right table. If I type out the string "AlabamaGeo" in the string tableselected it works but if I do is this way I get the error "Invalid Object name 'Alabama
Geo'. It separates Alabama and Geo in the error too.

Comment: Try to compare your tableName into which you want to insert something, and the table name which is stored on `tableSelected`

Comment: From you comment it seems there is a space inserted. Please try this: `string tableSelected = stateTextBox.Text.Trim() + "Geo";`

Comment: -1 for not passing the proper Parameters in `Comm.Parameters.AddWithValues` WOW...what a mess.. for starters I would suggest the following `1 wrap that code around a try {} except{}` Here is your Problem in these 2 lines `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);`
`comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", SqlDbType.NChar);`

Comment: the second argument in the Parameters.AddWithValue() needs to be a value ..not `sqlDBType. the error message you are getting is totally correct.. you need to refactor this totally..

Comment: @DJKRAZE is correct, I just checked the AddWithValue() function, it is `AddWithValue(string parameterName, object Value)`

Comment: I would also suggest if you are going to execute the Query in a foreach loop that you make a separate method passing in the proper Parameters because it's obvious that you have confused yourself. if you are going to pass values with string[] I would investigate looking at the .AddRange Method too. I personally would refactor that mess

Comment: Gian Acuna answered exactly what I was having an issue with. It all works now.